# How to enable DiskSpaceMetrics in io.micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-micrometer

io.micrometer contains disk space metrics (io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.DiskSpaceMetrics) but it doesn't seems to be enabled by default. There are no metric data. How do i enable this metric that it can be used by prometheus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metrics about disk space are exposed as part of the health endpoint, which is provided by Spring Boot Actuator (dependency: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator`).

The health endpoint can be enabled as follows in the `application.properties` file (by default, it should be enabled):

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
```

Then, you can enable detailed disk space information as follows:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-components=always
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
```

In production, you might want to use `when_authorized` instead of `always`, so that the information is not publicly available.

Finally, you can see the disk info through the HTTP endpoint `/actuator/health`.

More info in the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health).

---

The same metrics for Prometheus will be added in a future Spring Boot version. There's an [open PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/26001) to add auto configuration for that. In the meantime, you can configure a bean yourself taking inspiration from the PR.

```
@Bean
public DiskSpaceMetrics diskSpaceMetrics() {
    return new DiskSpaceMetrics(new File("."));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen that diskspace is part of the health route but  i would like to scrape it from prometheus.

Comment: I updated the answer to a link to an open PR to add autoconfiguration for DiskSpaceMetrics to Spring Boot. It's not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code of the class ***org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration***

The bean diskSpaceMetrics is defined as below.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public DiskSpaceMetricsBinder diskSpaceMetrics(MetricsProperties properties) {
    List<File> paths = properties.getSystem().getDiskspace().getPaths();
    return new DiskSpaceMetricsBinder(paths, (Iterable) Tags.empty());
}
```

I found that setting up the below property can serve the purpose of getting the desired metric.

```
management.metrics.system.diskspace.paths: <comma separated desired paths>
```

Example for set-up done with `/log` as path

```
management.metrics.system.diskspace.paths: /log
```

The Following Metrics are found in the Actuator Prometheus Endpoint

```
disk_free_bytes{path="/log",} 1.003487232E9
disk_total_bytes{path="/log",} 1.023410176E9
```

*Note I have been using Spring boot **3.2.1***