# How to enable disk space metrics in Spring-Boot/Micrometer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, micrometer

I have read over the Spring Metrics docs and I have `system` metrics enabled in my `application.yml` file.  This, according to the docs, is supposed to give me metrics prefixed with `process.`, `system.` and `disk.`.  I see results for the first two of these, but I am not getting any metrics about disk space usage.  I've even looked in the code and have found a `MeterBinder` class named `DiskSpaceMetrics` that seems to send the two values `disk.free` and `disk.total`.  Can someone please tell me how to get my Spring app to send these disk space metrics?

I am sending my metrics to AWS CloudWatch.

I found this Question:  [How to enable DiskSpaceMetrics in io.micrometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702664/how-to-enable-diskspacemetrics-in-io-micrometer).  It seems to be about seeing the disk space values in Spring's `actuator` dashboard.  I do see the values there.  What I want is for those values to be periodically reported as metrics values.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my app WAS sending out the metrics.  The AWS Cloudwatch console just wasn't showing them to me. I brought up the metrics just fine via Grafana.  Even once I knew they were there, I could find no way to get the AWS console to show them to me.  Strange.  I might have to put in a request to AWS asking them what's up with that.